# How to get the record with maximum id?

Tags: php, mysql, flourishlib

I am using MySQL with Flourish. Let's suppose I have a table called Foo and it has a column called id. My question is:

What is the flourish equivalent for the following query:

```
select * from Foo where id = (select max(id) from Foo);
```

Thanks

Comment: Why did you downvote the question? It is referring to the Flourishlib equivalent for the query. I am NOT asking for a MySQL query.

Comment: I am trying this: return fRecordSet::build('Foo')->sort('getId', 'desc')->getRecord(0);

Comment: Try `fRecordSet::build('Foo', null, array('id' => 'desc'))->getRecord(0);`

Comment: See my answer which solves the problem. There is no need for that null. It is interesting that the question is down-voted again while the answers (except mine) do not solve the problem and do not address even the problem. FDL's comment is a solution, but it seems it is unclear for him that we do not need that null in the parameter list. If the question is trivial, then why don't we see correct answers? If the question is unclear, then can someone specify what should be edited? I think the question is valid, it will help other people in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
public static function getLastFoo() {
    return fRecordSet::build('Foo')->sort('getId', 'desc')->getRecord(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not better way with ORDER BY and LIMIT?

```
SELECT * FROM Foo ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Use DESC for highest value.

Comment: Sorry, but I asked for the Flourish equivalent, not for a MySQL query.

Comment: Why are you upvoting this answer? It is NOT answering the question. The question asks for a Flourish equivalent of the query, NOT for a query.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select max(id),foo.* from foo order by id desc limit 1
```

Comment: Sorry, but I asked for the Flourish equivalent, not for a MySQL query.